# Swipe Views Tabs - How to set title properly?

Tags: android, tabs, view, swipe

As you can see in code on [Google](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) , they set TAB titles with hardcoded function.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
}
```

But I need to use strings from XML file to make TABS dependent on localization/language. I tried this and more, but I can´t figure out, how to solve it.  this is not working, because **"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context**". Any help is appreciated.

```
String [] titlesArray = new String []{ getString(R.string.TAB1), getString(R.string.TAB2), getString(R.string.TAB3), getString(R.string.TAB4), getString(R.string.TAB5), getString(R.string.TAB6)};

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titlesArray [position];
}
```

**Solution:
Find the way how to not use STATIC context. It is possible.**

Comment: return getString(R.string.TAB1) is not working, it return same error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Switch..Case.. block

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return res.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();

        case 1:
            return res.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();

        case 2:
            return res.getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();

        case 3:
            return res.getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase();

        case 4:
            return res.getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I always end with error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context". When I use code above, result is same : (

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use

```
        @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.TAB1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.TAB2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.TAB3);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.TAB4);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.TAB5);
            ...AND SO ON...
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but I always end with error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getString(int) from the type Context". When I use code above, result is same : (

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but i have found a working solution

Modify the PagerAdapter like this

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    static Context context;

    static Resources res = null;
    static String[] CONTENT = null;





    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Activity activity, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        res = context.getResources();
        CONTENT = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {

                return new PlaceHolderSignInFragment();
            }
            case 1: {
                return new PlaceHolderSignUpFragment();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SectionsPagerAdapter.CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return SectionsPagerAdapter.CONTENT[position];
    }

    public String[] getTitles() {
        return SectionsPagerAdapter.CONTENT;
    }
}
```

In case you need for future launches!!!!